# HTTP 405 After route RESTEasy request using ContainerRequestContext#setRequestUri

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, resteasy

I have the following scenario:

- A GET request is made to: http://localhost:8080/API/company/
- A ContainerRequestFilter is called:

  `@Provider
   @PreMatching
   public class RequestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter`
- A header is checked:

  `Boolean isTestEnv = Boolean.parseBoolean(requestContext.getHeaderString("isTestEnv"));
   if(isTestEnv){`
- In case of true, the URI is changed:

  `String url = requestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath().toString();
   String newURL = url.replaceFirst("/API/company", "/APISimulator/company/test");`
- The request is forwarded:

  `requestContext.setRequestUri(new URI(newURL));`

When I make a request to: http://localhost:8080/API/company/ the filter is triggered and the code is executed, but a HTTP 405 occurrs.

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: OPTIONS
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/9
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:29:21 GMT
```

If I remove the Header, the request occurrs succesfully

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/9
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:43:31 GMT

OK
```

Log:

```
2017-10-31 17:29:21,836 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-48) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:375)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Versions:

- Wildfly 9.0.2
- Resteasy 3.0.11

Answer (score 0):

I changed my interceptor to use the following WebFilter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        second(request, response, chain);
    }

    private void second(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String isTestEnv = httpRequest.getHeader("isTestEnv");

        if(isTestEnv != null && isTestEnv.equals("true")) {

            String url = getFullURL(httpRequest);
            String newURL = url.replaceFirst("/API/company", "/APISimulator/company/test");

            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
            res.setHeader("Location", newURL);  

        } else {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    public static String getFullURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
        StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();

        if (queryString == null) {
            return requestURL.toString();
        } else {
            return requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
        }
    }

}
```

And the request was successfully forwarded.